# Application Event Log with User Details

Tags: .net, windows

I have an eventlogger with exception in the app.config file.
How can I update the USER details in the eventlog?
Now its showing User : N/A

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

See [the MSDN page for EventLogEntry.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.username.aspx): "This property is often blank for events in logs other than the Security log."

I can't recall exactly where I read it, but I think it is even stronger than that. No other EventLog log can set the User attribute (and applications cannot write to the Security event log). So I think, what you try to do is not possible.

If it is indeed possible I would be interested as well ;-)